# adjust JTextField with JComboBox

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jtextfield, jcombobox

Please some one can told me why I don't have the JTextField in the same line with my JComboBox ?
I need to have like that:

```
myJComboBox1      JTextField1
                  JTextField2
myJComboBox2      JTextField1
                  JTextField2
```

following this example

```
public class DisplayPanel extends JFrame {

    private JComboBox[] box;
JTextField[] field1, field2;

public DisplayPanel(){
    super(BorderLayoutTest.class.getName());
    setTitle("Simulation");
    setSize(1000,500);
    setResizable(false);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    createComponents();
    initComponents();
}

private void createComponents(){

    box = new JComboBox[3];
    field1 = new JTextField[4];
    field2 = new JTextField[5];     
}



private void initComponents(){
     setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));

     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
         box[i] =new JComboBox<>(new String[] { "field1", "field2"});
         panel.add(box[i], BorderLayout.NORTH);
         add(panel);
         add(createPanelWithTextFields(panel));
         box[i].setSelectedIndex(-1);
         box[i].addActionListener(new CustomActionListener(box[i]));
        }

}

private Component createPanelWithTextFields(JPanel panel) {
  //need to keep the same layout as JComboBox
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

    for(int x=0; x<4; x++){
        field1[x] = new JTextField("field1 Name " + (x+1));
        field1[x].setVisible(false);   
        panel.add(field1[x]);
    }

    for(int x=0; x<5; x++){
        field2[x] = new JTextField("field2 Name " + (x+1));
        field2[x].setVisible(false);     
        panel.add(field2[x]);
    }

    return panel;
}


class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener {
    JComboBox b;

    public CustomActionListener(JComboBox u) {
        super();
        this.b = u;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int numChosen = b.getSelectedIndex() + 1;

        switch (numChosen){
        case 1:
            for(int x=0; x<4; x++)
                field1[x].setVisible(true);
            break;
        case 2:
            for(int x=0; x<5; x++)
                field2[x].setVisible(true);
            break;
        }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            new DisplayPanel().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: @ControlAltDel nope 0 mean row count is unknown it can be any but one column

Comment: you assign new `textfield`  to textfield array so at the end of the the loop your field array contain reference to textfields of last panel.

Comment: @FastSnail I think you are right. How about ajusting JTextField in the same line with my JComboBox ?

Comment: @Mehdi how much jtextfields should have in a one panel?

Comment: @FastSnail in each panel i have one myJComboBox and depending of what user choose from, i diplay the jtextfields. So, I can display 10 jtextfields or more or less it depends on myJComboBox choice.

Comment: @Mehdi but currently you have declare `field1 = new JTextField[4];` i'm asking why?

Comment: @FastSnail field1 is the jtextfields that i should display when user chose field1 from myJComboBox. Just that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87499/discussion-between-mehdi-and-fast-snail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are assigning new textfield to textfield array.but it contain only 4 textfields.but you call assigning more than 4 times.so what happening is last rextfield references get reassigning and you can't use them again.at the end of the the loop your field array contain reference to textfields of last panel.and that's why your see textfields on last panel even you select from combobox1.

how to fix ?

change this

```
 field1 = new JTextField[4];
```

to this

```
field1 = new JTextField[4 * 3];
```

and then you don't need to reassign jtextfields .you have 3 panels and you have 4 textfields for each panel.

same for field2

here is an example .

```
public class DisplayPanel extends JFrame {

    private JComboBox[] box;
    JTextField[] field1, field2;
    Color col[] = {Color.red, Color.GREEN, Color.blue};
    int i = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    private int boxcount;
    int field1counter = 0;
    int field2counter = 0;

    public DisplayPanel() {
        //super(BorderLayoutTest.class.getName());
        setTitle("Simulation");
        setSize(1000, 500);
        //setResizable(false);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        createComponents();
        initComponents();
    }

    private void createComponents() {

        boxcount = 3;
        box = new JComboBox[1 * boxcount];
        field1 = new JTextField[4 * boxcount];
        field2 = new JTextField[5 * boxcount];
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            box[i] = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"field1", "field2"});
            panel.add(box[i], BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(panel);
            add(createPanelWithTextFields(panel));
            box[i].setSelectedIndex(-1);
            box[i].addActionListener(new CustomActionListener());
        }

    }

    private Component createPanelWithTextFields(JPanel panelc) {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.setBackground(col[i]);
        System.out.println("......................");
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            System.out.println("iterating .." + (field1counter) + "  counter  " + counter);
            field1[field1counter] = new JTextField("field1 Name " + (x + 1));
            field1[field1counter].setVisible(false);
            panel.add(field1[field1counter]);
            field1counter++;
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            field2[field2counter] = new JTextField("field2 Name " + (x + 1));
            field2[field2counter].setVisible(false);
            panel.add(field2[field2counter]);
            field2counter++;
        }
        i++;
        counter++;
        return panel;
    }

    class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JComboBox b = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
            int comboidenty = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < box.length; k++) {
                if (box[k] == b) {
                    break;
                }
                comboidenty++;
            }
            System.out.println(((JPanel) (b.getParent())).getBackground());
            int numChosen = b.getSelectedIndex() + 1;

            System.out.println("hi " + comboidenty);
            switch (numChosen) {
                case 1:
                    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                        System.out.println("field1  " + (comboidenty * 4 + x));
                        field1[comboidenty * 4 + x].setVisible(true);
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
                        System.out.println("field2  " + (comboidenty * 5 + x));
                        field2[comboidenty * 5 + x].setVisible(true);
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DisplayPanel().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks about your program. But you have the same problem as me. Try to choose field2 from your JComboBox.

Comment: @Mehdi why when you select field2 in first panel

Comment: @Mehdi that's possible but not a good idea .understand your designing you have jtextfield in all 3 panel.what you do is hide and show ...so if you select field 2 field2 textfields will be visible but field one textfields are there  but hide.consider using layout card

Comment: euuh no no sorry xD. But when you chose field2 it displays under field1 which is invisible. Can i remove field1 JTextField when i choose field2 from JComboBox ? –